# Entity loads all navigation properties after disabled LazyLoading

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework 4.0 Data First Model. I have disabled the lazy loading on my edmx like

```
 LazyLoadingEnabled=false
```

I have also disabled the loading in context constructor like..

```
public AMSNextGen_CustomerCare() : base(ConnectionString, ContainerName)
{
   ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;            
   OnContextCreated();
}
```

But when I select a single entity then it will get its reference navigation entities. using the select statement like this

```
return disEdmx.Tax_TaxRule.SingleOrDefault(x => x.TaxRuleID == ruleId);
```

I am not using Eagerly or Explicitly loading with statement. Please help and give any solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are your navigation properties `virtual`?

Comment: Yes, I am using POCO classes , So every property is virtual property. But I think removing virtual keyword for disabling lazyloading is working in 4+ entity framework.